# firebase upload after checkout

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is shopping app after user select the products send to cart then checkout after fill the fields and press Checkout (Pay) send the details of the products to my firebase database please any one can help me I use json as my load products on tableview cell

I know I don't have payment serves but on this fields of payment information will be name , phone number, and location

```
[{
    "name": "EGG",
    "price": "3.00",
    "image": "http://partiklezoo.com/Egg/u0001.jpg",
    "description": "one Egg",
    "category": "Food",
    "uid": "u0001"
},]
```

Code

```
import UIKit

class CheckoutViewController: DetailViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var cardNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var cardExpiryMonth: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var cardExpiryYear: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var cardCvv: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var pickerPickupPoint: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet var tableViewOrderDetails: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var labelTotalPrice: UILabel!


    var model = SingletonManager.model

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.configureCheckout()

        self.tableViewOrderDetails.dataSource = self
        self.tableViewOrderDetails.delegate = self

        self.pickerPickupPoint.dataSource = self
        self.pickerPickupPoint.delegate = self

        //Looks for single or multiple taps.
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CheckoutViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func configureCheckout() {

        pickerPickupPoint.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)

        labelTotalPrice.text = "$" + String(format: "%.2f", model.calculateCartTotal())

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model.cart.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = model.products[Int(model.cart[indexPath.row][0])].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(Int(model.cart[indexPath.row][1])) + " x $" + String(format: "%.2f", model.cart[indexPath.row][4])

        return cell
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return model.pickUpLocations.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return model.pickUpLocations[row]["street"]! + ", " + model.pickUpLocations[row]["suburb"]!
    }

    @IBAction func payNow(_ sender: Any) {

        var error = ""


        if self.model.cart.count == 0 {
            error = "Your cart is empty."
        }
        else if (self.cardNumber.text?.isEmpty)! {
            error = "Please enter your card number."
        }
        else if (self.cardExpiryMonth.text?.isEmpty)! {
            error = "Please enter the expiry month of your card."
        }
        else if (self.cardExpiryYear.text?.isEmpty)! {
            error = "Please enter the expiry year of your card."
        }
        else if (self.cardCvv.text?.isEmpty)!{
            error = "Please enter the CVV number of your card."
        }



        if error.isEmpty {

            showAlertMsg("Confirm Purchase", message: "Pay " + labelTotalPrice.text!, style: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

        }
        else {
            showAlertMsg("Error", message: error, style: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        }

    }

    var alertController: UIAlertController?

    func showAlertMsg(_ title: String, message: String, style: UIAlertControllerStyle) {

        self.alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: style)

        if style == UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet {
            alertController?.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Pay", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                self.checkout()
            }))

            alertController?.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
        } else {
            alertController?.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default))
        }

        self.present(self.alertController!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }







    func checkout() {


        var success = true

        for count in 0...self.model.cart.count - 1 {

            let product = self.model.products[Int(self.model.cart[count][0])]
            let quantity = Int(self.model.cart[count][1])
            let total = self.model.cart[count][4]

            let material = self.model.cart[count][3] == 0.0 ? "pla" : "abs"
            let painting = self.model.cart[count][2] == 0.0 ? "false" : "true"


            let temp = self.model.purchase(product: product, quantity: quantity, total: total, material: material, painting: painting)

            if !temp {
                success = false
            }

        }

        if !success {
            let error = "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later."
            showAlertMsg("Error", message: error, style: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        } else {
            print("Success! Checkout complete.")

            self.cardNumber.text = ""
            self.cardExpiryMonth.text = ""
            self.cardExpiryYear.text = ""
            self.cardCvv.text = ""

            self.labelTotalPrice.text = "$0.00"

            self.model.clearCart()
            self.tableViewOrderDetails.reloadData()

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Thankyou", sender: self)

        }

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let confirmationVc = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! ConfirmationViewController

        confirmationVc.location = self.model.pickUpLocations[self.pickerPickupPoint.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]


    }

}
```

> this is my objective

```
Class Model: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var segueArray = [String]()
var seguesDictionary = Dictionary<String, UIImage>()

var products = [Product]()
var storedProducts = [NSManagedObject]()

var cart = [[Double]]()
var storedCart = [NSManagedObject]()

var pickUpLocations = [[String: String]]()

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override init() {

    super.init()

    segueArray.append("Home")
    segueArray.append("List")
    segueArray.append("Search")
    segueArray.append("Cart")
    segueArray.append("Finder")
    segueArray.append("Checkout")

    seguesDictionary["Home"] = UIImage(named: "home")
    seguesDictionary["List"] = UIImage(named: "list")
    seguesDictionary["Search"] = UIImage(named: "search")
    seguesDictionary["Cart"] = UIImage(named: "cart")
    seguesDictionary["Finder"] = UIImage(named: "finder")
    seguesDictionary["Checkout"] = UIImage(named: "checkout")

    self.loadProducts()
    self.refreshProducts()
    self.loadCart()
    self.configureLocManager()
}

func loadProducts() {
    let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Products")

    do {

        let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        storedProducts = results as! [NSManagedObject]

        if storedProducts.count > 0 {
            for index in 0...storedProducts.count - 1 {

                let binaryData = storedProducts[index].value(forKey: "image") as! Data
                let image = UIImage(data: binaryData)

                let name = storedProducts[index].value(forKey: "name") as! String
                let price = storedProducts[index].value(forKey: "price") as! Double
                let details = storedProducts[index].value(forKey: "details") as! String
                let category = storedProducts[index].value(forKey: "category") as! String
                let uid = storedProducts[index].value(forKey: "uid") as! String

                let loadedProduct = Product(name: name, price: price, image: image!, details: details, category: category, uid: uid)

                products.append(loadedProduct)

            }
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("Could not load. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

func refreshProducts() {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://partiklezoo.com/3dprinting/")
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    config.isDiscretionary = true
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url! as URL, completionHandler:
    {(data, response, error) in

        let json = JSON(data: data!)

        for count in 0...json.count - 1
        {
            let newProduct = Product()
            newProduct.name = json[count]["name"].string
            newProduct.price = Double(json[count]["price"].string!)
            newProduct.details = json[count]["description"].string
            newProduct.category = json[count]["category"].string
            newProduct.uid = json[count]["uid"].string

            let imgURL = json[count]["image"].string!

            self.addItemToList(newProduct, imageURL: imgURL)
        }

    })
    task.resume()
}

func checkForProduct(_ searchItem: Product) -> Int {
    var targetIndex = -1

    if products.count > 0 {
        for index in 0...products.count - 1 {
            if products[index].uid == searchItem.uid {
                targetIndex = index
            }
        }

    }

    return targetIndex
}

func addItemToList(_ newProduct: Product!, imageURL: String) {

    if checkForProduct(newProduct) == -1 {
        let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let picture = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(loadImage(imageURL), 1)
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Products", in: managedContext)
        let productToAdd = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)

        productToAdd.setValue(newProduct.category, forKey: "category")
        productToAdd.setValue(newProduct.details, forKey: "details")
        productToAdd.setValue(picture, forKey: "image")
        productToAdd.setValue(newProduct.name, forKey: "name")
        productToAdd.setValue(newProduct.price, forKey: "price")
        productToAdd.setValue(newProduct.uid, forKey: "uid")

        do
        {
            try managedContext.save()
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        storedProducts.append(productToAdd)
        newProduct.image = UIImage(data: picture!)
        products.append(newProduct)

    }
}

func loadCart() {
    let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Cart")

    do {

        let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        storedCart = results as! [NSManagedObject]

        if storedCart.count > 0 {
            for index in 0...storedCart.count - 1 {

                let product = storedCart[index].value(forKey: "product") as! Double
                let quantity = storedCart[index].value(forKey: "quantity") as! Double
                let finish = storedCart[index].value(forKey: "finish") as! Double
                let material = storedCart[index].value(forKey: "material") as! Double
                let totalPrice = storedCart[index].value(forKey: "total") as! Double

                let temp = [product, quantity, finish, material, totalPrice]

                cart.append(temp)

            }
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("Could not load. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}

func addToCart(product: Product, quantity: Double, finish: Double, material: Double, totalPrice: Double) {
    let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Cart", in: managedContext)
    let productToAdd = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)
    productToAdd.setValue(checkForProduct(product), forKey: "product")
    productToAdd.setValue(quantity, forKey: "quantity")
    productToAdd.setValue(finish, forKey: "finish")
    productToAdd.setValue(material, forKey: "material")
    productToAdd.setValue(totalPrice, forKey: "total")

    do
    {
        try managedContext.save()
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    let temp = [Double(checkForProduct(product)), quantity, finish, material, totalPrice]

    storedCart.append(productToAdd)
    cart.append(temp)

}
```

Comment: There's quite a bit of code there and it's unclear what it does or what the question is. Are you asking how to [Read and Write Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) to Firebase?

Comment: no. I am asking how I can let the products in carts after checkout send all the details of products to my firebases

Comment: So... you want to store the products that are in a cart in Firebase? What's stopping that process from happening? Where is your cart object and Firebase code of what you've attempted so far?

Comment: 1-yes 2- I will upload the objectives 3- i don't know what I can do to store the details

Comment: Great! Where's your code to write that data to Firebase? If you need help getting started, go through the Firebase Getting started guide I linked in my first comment. That will demonstrate the process to write data to Firebase.

Comment: but this process  where I can put it in the action of button or with objects if u can write one example code for me to understand

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question but from the comments I believe the OP is asking for example code to put into an action button to write date to Firebase. So here it is.

(note: please see comments as the OP didn't clarify what he was after so it's not clear if this is an answer or not)

Start with initialzing Firebase in your view controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
```

then lets have a button press write two cars to firebase in a 'car_list' node

```
 @IBAction func button0Action(_ sender: Any) {
        let itemDict0 = [
            "Name": "Car",
            "price": "2000"]

        let itemDict1 = [
            "Name": "Car",
            "price": "3000"]

        let carRef = self.ref.child("car_list")

        carRef.childByAutoId().setValue(itemDict0)
        carRef.childByAutoId().setValue(itemDict1)
    }
```

and the result in Firebase looks like this

```
car_list
   -LKYuRKpLL_JXsDGsYWY
      Name: "Car"
      Price: "2000"
   -LKYuRKpLL_JXsDGsYWZ
      Name: "Car"
      Price: "3000"
```

EDIT: I had intially set this up like a grocery list per the data in the question but per a comment from the OP they want to make it cars and prices, so that's how it is now.

Comment: yes like this put my details that come from cart  for example. Name: Car. Price:2000.

Comment: @veto1122 Ok, I updated the answer to write two cars to Firebase.

Comment: But not same I want

Comment: @veto1122 I don't understand that last comment. If the answer works and is helping you be sure to accept it so it can help others.

Comment: you can see my other question that will more explain.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989442/send-to-firebase-database

Comment: @veto1122 It's the same question and it does't add any more information. I believe you asked how to save your product/car information to Firebase (*send the details of the products to my firebase database*) and this answer supplies that code. You can simply add key: value pairs of qty, finish, url image link and material to the dictionaries in my answer and those will be written as well. What else are you wanting to accomplish?

Comment: I don't now how to explain for you but you have now shopping app that contains categories and cart when users select products send to cart then checkout when user checkout automatically the products chosen  goes in firebase to start preparing  to deriver to customer

Comment: @veto1122 The code in my answer takes the selected shopping card item, two cars in this case, and writes it to Firebase. What additional code do you need?